# Swig - return byte array from C++ method

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm using Swig 3.0 with Java and C++ code and need to return from C++ a byte array (binary data, not text).

The problem with the byte array is that I need not only the buffer, but the size too. Is it possible to map a struct with `char *` and `size_t` as fields and map using this tool?

Comment: I'm mapping the output using std::string in c++ and byte[] in java.